# How to orientate many pictures well when pdfjoin *.jpg?

Tags: pdf, join

I am combining .jpg images which are correctly positioned in their jpg files. 
So I think this position could be passed to an view format like pdf. 
So I am doing now the following but it gives pictures in quite randomly positioned

```
pdfjoin *.jpg
```

Comment: You mean the pictures are rotated in the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exif data did not help here, neither `pdfjoin`. 
LaTeX is the right tool for the task in the thread [How to rotate image 90 if height overful?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341551/how-to-rotate-image-90-if-height-overful/341553#341553) 
The case where both figure dimensions are greater than the page size is not solved. 
I think you cannot solve the case by `exiftool` and `pdfjoin` directly because you have to related pictures to each other such that they are nicely orientated in the page.